# What will happen if iOS distribution certificate expired?

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate

I'm now submitting iPhone app to iTunes connect.
And I have a question about distribution certificate.

What will happen if distribution certificate expired?

Will apps which purchased by users stop running or crash after certificate expired?

Or users can't install the apps or can't download the apps from App Store after expiration of distribution certificate?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If distribution certificate expired then you can't submit apps in Apple Store. Existing/Submitted apps will work fine. No need to worry about it.

Comment: What If I'm going to add a version to the previously made applications but the provision used before had a certificate that got expired.

Comment: What about updating live apps in app store? If the certificate expires will I be able to update the app running on app store?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing happens. Don't worry about it.

You can also refer : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2333107?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

> Previous submitted apps will be working as well.No need to worry about
>   it.

This is not completely true.  For the remainder of the certificates one year life the app will run.   After the certificate expires the app in the store and on user devices will cease to run. Without a current membership you won't be able to renew the certificate.

See the following link:
https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/certificates/

Comment: This is not correct. Per the link posted above: "
If your iOS Developer Program membership is valid, your existing apps on the App Store will not be affected. However, you will no longer be able to submit new apps or updates to the App Store."

Comment: I think you are mixing the "Developer account licence" and "Distribution certificate". If you developer account is active (you payed for one year 100$) and your distribution certificate is valid you can upload apps onto the app store. If your "Distribution certificate" expires , your (approved) app will not be removed and will still work, however if your "Developer account licence" expires (you have not payed 100$) your app will be removed from the store and will stop working on the user devices. Please correct me if I understood it incorreclty

Comment: Was actually referring to my experience as an enterprise developer.  I never submitted apps to the store, but we installed them directly from our portal or pushed them via MSM.